# splitting list elements expanding the list

Tags: r, list, split, ocr, expand

I'm doing some kind of optical character recognition and face the following issue. I store the glyphs in a list of binary matrices and they can be of different size, but their maximum possible width is `wid = 3` columns (may be any defined constant, not just 3). In some cases after the first stage of processing I get data which look like this:

```
myll <- list(matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), ncol = 2),
             matrix(c(0), ncol = 1),
             matrix(c(1, 1, 0), ncol = 3),
             matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 7),
             matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 2))
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    0    1
# [3,]    0    0
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    0
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
# 
# [[5]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
```

So, some glyphs may be not separated for some reasons. This happens only with glyphs of maximum possible width. Moreover, there may be some junk at the end of the matrix. I have to split them into matrices of width `ncol = wid` leaving the last piece (junk) as is. Then I store this matrices in separate elements of list to get the following output:

```
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    0    1
# [3,]    0    0
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    0
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    0    1    0
# [3,]    1    1    1
# 
# [[5]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    0
# 
# [[6]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    1
# [3,]    1
# 
# [[7]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
```

At the moment I can make it with the help of this functions

```
checkGlyphs <- function(gl_m, wid = 3) {
  if (ncol(gl_m) > wid) 
    return(list(gl_m[,1:wid], matrix(gl_m[,-(1:wid)], nrow = nrow(gl_m)))) else
    return(gl_m)
}

separateGlyphs <- function(myll, wid = 3) {
  require("magrittr")

  presplit <- lapply(myll, checkGlyphs, wid) 
  total_new_length <- 
    presplit[unlist(lapply(presplit, is.list))] %>% lapply(length) %>% unlist() %>% sum() +
    as.integer(!unlist(lapply(presplit, is.list))) %>% sum()

  splitted <- vector("list", length = total_new_length)
  spl_index <- 1
  for (i in 1:length(presplit)) 
  {
    if (!is.list(presplit[[i]])) 
    {   
      splitted[[spl_index]] <- presplit[[i]]
      spl_index <- spl_index + 1 
    } else
    { 
      for (j in 1:length(presplit[[i]]))
      {   
        splitted[[spl_index]] <- presplit[[i]][[j]]
        spl_index <- spl_index + 1 
      }
    }
  }

  if (any(lapply(splitted, ncol) > wid)) return(separateGlyphs(splitted, wid)) else
    return(splitted)
}
```

But I believe there is more fast and convenient way to achieve the same result (without using `for` loops and this enlooped reassignment of elements and then recursion if needed O_o).

I will be thankful for any suggestions on the point or, alternatively, for recommending some OCR-packages for R.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, with the values in `final` being what you're after.

```
combined <- do.call(cbind, lapply(myll, unlist))
idx <- seq(1, ncol(combined), 2)
final <- do.call(list, lapply(idx, function(x) combined[, x:(x+1)]))
```

Comment: yes, but... it merges all matrices in one and then re-splits them by fixed width, but really in my list I can have matrices with different number of columns... I wrote they are all the same, but its wrong, I just wanted to simplify the situation. The issue is I need not to touch good matrices (copy as they are) and operate only with those which are too wide. I'll make editions to my question.

Comment: Please mention the criteria used to determine if a matrix is "too wide" (my presumption was > 2) and confirm if the handling is "split them by fixed width" as you mentioned in your post.